# Next JS Next Page Function component is not a function declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I just got started with using TypeScript in Next JS and I keep getting this eslint error even after trying what the eslint docs say:

Here is my component:

```
import type { NextPage } from "next";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>Home</>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

The code however displays the eslint error: `Function component is not a function declarationeslintreact/function-component-definition`.

I tried to use it this way but also got errors:

```
export default function Home<NextPage> () {
    return (
        <div>Home</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can simply use a function declaration without the type: `export default function Home() { return (<div>Home</div>) }`.